# Safari (iOS and Desktop) brightening background images when animating with CSS

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, css-animations

basically I need to apply a CSS animation where the background-image property of an element changes at certain keyframes, but I don't want it to animate. Now, background-image isn't an animatable property so this shouldn't be an issue anyway, but most browsers have just decided to go ahead and tween it anyway, so I have to mitigate that. I tried this sort of hack:

```
@keyframes animation {
  0%, 100% {
    background-image: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/72/7016712-nice-love-wallpaper-27705.jpg);
  }
  49.9999% {
    background-image: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/72/7016712-nice-love-wallpaper-27705.jpg);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/31/6875628-nice-backgrounds.jpg)
  }
[...]
```

Full code on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKPXYj?editors=110

Which works fine, except on Safari (both iOS and Desktop), where the images have this sort of brightening effect as they "animate" even though the property isn't changing between keyframes... Can anyone think of a way to avoid this happening, I just want the images to change without animating, and without this strange brightening.

Comment: I don't have a solution but I will add that this happens because Safari is trying to crossfade the background image A to B, but because the background image A is the same as B, both are at 50% transparent at the same time and the background color bleeds through. This is the 'brightening' you're seeing - the white background color with the background at 50% opacity. This doesn't happen on firefox or chrome because their crossfade implementation isn't completely stupid.